# Loading http feed on https context using HttpWebRequest fires 400 bad request

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm running the below code to access a variety of RSS http URLs, but my web application executing the code is on https.

```
HttpWebRequest request = 
   (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(blog["RSSURL"].ToString()));
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.ProhibitDtd = false;
XmlReader reader =  
   XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream(), readerSettings);                        
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
```

When I fire this I get :

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Can anyone help me to figure out how I fix this?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the error in a browser, or can you get to the feed normally in a browser?

Comment: Can yo show the content of `blog["RSSURL"]`?

Comment: Yes can get access to the urls in the browser.

Comment: An example of a RSS feed is http://blog.sharepointelearning.com/feed/

Comment: I iterate through a series of these urls. I do .Close() off the response and reader objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample url works for me

```
string url = "http://blog.sharepointelearning.com/feed/";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(url);
var items = xDoc.Descendants("item")
        .Select(item => new 
        {
            Title = item.Element("title").Value,
            Link = item.Element("link").Value,
            Description = item.Element("description").Value,
        })
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: yes, but are you on a SSL web application when executing it calling this http url?

Comment: I can not see what would change?

Comment: It works for feedburner urls that end in ?format=xml. After reading around it looks like its to do with cross domain scripting and feedburner have a way to fix this. But other sites don't.

Comment: When using your url's in c# client, there shouldn't be any problem. XSS  is only related with javascript, not with c# client.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought. I remember reading something about this though http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Feb/11/HttpWebRequest-and-Ignoring-SSL-Certificate-Errors
but this was for HTTP calling HTTPS.

Comment: I am lost. Just show me an example that doesn't work. Otherwise I don't think I can help you.